# How to set Searchkick boost_by_distance?

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, mongoid, searchkick

I try to write query by Searchkick with boost_by_distance. But seems the nearest location is not boosted.
And I would like to find any place in 30km distance from city and also boost result by in 20km more.
But Nothing return even testing by the place very close geolocation from city geolocation.

main.rb

```
...  
city = City.search(params[:city], fields: [{city: :word_start}])
...     
@o = Organization.search("*",
        boost_by_distance: {field: :loc, origin: [city[0].try(:latitude).to_f, city[0].try(:longitude).to_f], function: :gauss, scale: "20km", decay: 0.5},
        where: {loc: {near: [city[0].try(:latitude).to_f, city[0].try(:longitude).to_f], within: "30km"}},
        page: params[:page], per_page: 20)
...
```

organization.rb

```
class Organization
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Geospatial

  searchkick index_name: "organization",
             locations: ["loc"],
             word_start: ['base']

  def search_data
      attributes.merge loc: [latitude, longitude]
    {
      base: base,
      place: place
    }
  end

  field :base,     type: Srting
  field :place,     type: Srting
  field :latitude,     type: Float
  field :longitude,     type: Float
  field :location, type: Point, spatial: true

  index({ base: 1, place: 1, location: "2d" })

end
```

city.rb

```
class City
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Geospatial

  searchkick index_name: "city",
             word_start: ['city']

  def search_data
    {
      city: city,
    }
  end

  field :city,            type: String
  field :latitude,         type: Float
  field :longitude,         type: Float

end
```

I tried many way to write search_data, because maybe own organization.rb search_data is not correct.
Also I checked loc FIELDS in Browser at http://localhost:9200/_plugin/head/ , but no input fields.
Please let me know what is wrong or how to check actually sending query.

Comment: I don't know if you are still looking for an answer but if you or anyone else is - stop using the array to send a location to search kick and use a hash with :lat, :lon keys so it knows exactly which is which.  We had this problem for a long time and it was fixed when searchkick started accepting hashes and we changed everything over to use a hash for location where possible.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it on next project.